# c function to compare highest values of two different arrays (applied to tiebreaking highcard hands in poker)

Tags: c, arrays, poker

```
#include <stdio.h>

int highcard (int array[])
    {
        int i, j;
        int largest = array[0];
        for (i=0; i<5; i++)
            {
                if (largest < array[i])
                    {
                        largest = array[i];
                    }
            }

        printf("largest element is %d", largest);
        return largest;
    }




int main()
    {
        int hand1[5]={8, 10, 6 , 4, 2};
        int hand2[5]={13, 5, 3, 9, 12};
        int largest;

        highcard(hand1[5]);
        int largest1 = largest;
        return largest1;

        highcard(hand2[5]);
        int largest2 = largest;
        return largest2;

        if (largest1 < largest2)
            {
               printf("winner: hand2");
            }
        else
            {
                printf("winner: hand1");
            }
        return 0;
    }
```

I am trying to develop a program that tiebreaks two highcard hands in poker. For this I "translate" the card values to numbers (2=2 ... A=14), and for this specific case the maximum array size will always be 5 (5 cards). My problem is how do I compare the return values of the same function when applied to two different arrays?

What I mean is:

- I have hand(array)1
- I have hand2
- I determine the largest number of hand1 and return it
- I do the same thing for hand2
- In main(), I want to compare the return (largest number) of highcard applied to hand1 and then hand2

But how do I specify in main() the specific return value of function highcard when applied to hand1 and then hand2 and keeping both returns separated?

This is what I have tried so far.

P.S.: This is for a university/college project, I have only started programming this semester, so any detailed explanation of my mistakes/errors and how to correct them would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several misundertstandings.

```
highcard(hand1[5]);
```

Here, you want to call the function highcard and pass in the 5-element array `hand1`. To do that, do not specify the dimension in brackets. That works only when you declare the array. What happens instead is that you pass the sixth element of `hand1` -- the first element has index 0 -- to the function. That element does not exist. You should also get a warning, because an integer is not an array; the argument types don't match.

```
return largest1;
```

Here, you probably want to store something in `largest1`, but what you actually do is to return from the function with the given value. That means you leave the current function. Leaving `main` means that you stop the program. You don't need a `return` here, just store the value.

```
int largest1 = largest;
```

Here, you try to access the variable `largest` from `highcard`, but thzat variable is local `highcard` and therefore is not visible to your `main` function. Rhe `largest` you look at is just an unrelated, uninitialized variable.

You can access the value that is returned from a function by assigning the result of a function call like so. Your `main` function should look like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int hand1[5] = {8, 10, 6 , 4, 2};
    int hand2[5] = {13, 5, 3, 9, 12};

    int largest1 = highcard(hand1);
    int largest2 = highcard(hand2);

    if (largest1 < largest2) {
        printf("winner: hand2");
    } else {
        printf("winner: hand1");
    }

    return 0;
}
```